# Creating a HTML Table from nested JSON using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sample JSON like this:

```
 }
   "vehicles":"4door",
   "cars": {
   "Toyota":"Camry",
   "Ford":"Explorer",
   "Nissan":"Altima",
   "Jeep":"Wrangler"
   },
   "color":"red"
 }
```

I'm trying to make an HTML table with 2 columns called something like "Make" and "Model" using the sample JSON with JQuery using the "cars" array out of the JSON without taking the other items vehicles and color. The "Make" would be the keys of the JSON and the "Model" would be the values of the keys. I'm trying to get it to look something like this below but in a table format. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Make    Model
Toyota  Camry
Ford    Explorer
Nissan  Altima
Jeep    Wrangler
```

Comment: Have you started writing any JavaScript to parse it?

Comment: Am I the only one feeling weird about that car object? It should be `”cars”: [{ “make”: “Nissan”, “model”: “Almera” }, {...}]`, shouldn’t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` which will give an array of `keys`Then you can iterate it and get the `key` `value` from the object and use template literals to create a row and finally append to the `table`

```js
let cars = {
  "Toyota": "Camry",
  "Ford": "Explorer",
  "Nissan": "Altima",
  "Jeep": "Wrangler"
}

let getKeys = Object.keys(cars);


let row = '';
for (let i = 0; i < getKeys.length; i++) {
  row += `<tr><td>${getKeys[i]}</td><td>${cars[getKeys[i]]}</td></tr>`
}

$('#carTable').append(row)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='carTable'>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! The other solution worked as well but I can only choose one answer. So I went with this one. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys` to get an array of the cars and loop through them using `forEach` loop. Using `append` in jquery append the row to the table

```js
var data = {
  "vehicles": "4door",
  "cars": {
    "Toyota": "Camry",
    "Ford": "Explorer",
    "Nissan": "Altima",
    "Jeep": "Wrangler"
  },
  "color": "red"
}
var str='';
Object.keys(data.cars).forEach(e => {
  str+='<tr><td>' + e + '</td><td>' + data.cars[e] + '</td></tr>';
})
$('#data').append(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <td>Make</td>
    <td>Model</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked as well. I can only choose one answer though. But I upvoted to hopefully show others that come across this question to show that this answer works as well. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your entire html from the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var html = ""
var json = {
"vehicles":"4door",
"cars": {
"Toyota":"Camry",
"Ford":"Explorer",
"Nissan":"Altima",
"Jeep":"Wrangler"
},
"color":"red"
}
html = "<table><thead><th><td>Make</td><td>Model</td></th></thead><tbody>"
for(var x in json.cars){
    html+= "<tr><td>"+ x +"</td><td>"+ json.cars[x] +"</td></tr>"
}
html+="</tbody></table>"
$("#main").append(html)
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I seen json format was not correct also get `jsonObject.KeyName` hold in variable then loop json that holds variable.

```
var obj = {"Toyota":"Camry",   "Ford":"Explorer",   "Nissan":"Altima",   Jeep":"Wrangler"};
for (var key in obj) {  
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = obj[key];
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

After that you implement in html format.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
   "vehicles": "4door",
    "cars": {
        "Toyota": "Camry",
        "Ford": "Explorer",
        "Nissan": "Altima",
         "Jeep": "Wrangler"
    },
   "color": "red"
};
var cars = data.cars; // for better performance if large table
var tableData = Object.keys(cars).map(item => '<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td>' + cars[item] + '</td></tr>').join('');

$('#main>table').append(tableData)


<div id="main">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Make</td>
        <td>Model</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```